# How to iterate over a nested list

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi I have a hibernate query which is giving me a list with type `List<List<integer>>`.
How can I iterate this? My hibernate query is:

```
String SQL_QUERY = "select DISTINCT cbl.franchiseId,cbl.resellerId from 
     CustomerBusinessLocation cbl where cbl.cmcustLocId in (:locationId)";

Query query = getSession().createQuery(SQL_QUERY); 

query.setParameterList("locationId", customerLocId);

List<List<Integer>> rc_list = query.list();
```

Alternatively, is there any other way to easily pull in this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query doesn't return a `List<List<Integer>>`. It returns a `List<Object[]>`. The `Object[]` arrays contain one element per requested field. In your case, each `Object[]` will contain `franchiseId` at index 0 and `resellerId` at index 1.

This is of course explained in [the reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select).

The iteration should thus look like this:

```
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    Integer franchiseId = (Integer) row[0];
    Integer resellerId = (Integer) row[1];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To iterate nested lists, you simply nest for loops.

```
for(List<Integer> list : rc_list){
    for(Integer i : list){
      //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working showing " java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List"

Comment: @Khoyendra: See JB Nizet's answer for why you're not getting what you expect.